# How long dos it take for the federal government to make a disability retirement decision?

Tags: united-states, disabilities

I'm currently going through the disability retirement procedure, and was wondering how long it takes for the federal government to determine if you can retire with a disability, or if they can fire you without any recourse.

Comment: Is the federal government your employer?  If not, they cannot fire you.

Comment: In your earlier questions you mentioned you are covered by a collective bargaining agreement. That should have the answer to the second question.

Comment: Yes, the federal government is my employer. My CBU is just telling me to quit, and I wouldn't get anything in return as they don't care at all about their members.

Comment: They fired me for becoming mentally unfit to work as a Merchant Marine after an assault.